# How to get the relevant error message when using React-hook-forms in a loop ,

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a loop that creates input fields. I managed to make it validate using react-hook-form and yup. but I cannot get the error message because of a variable issue...

```
{Object.getOwnPropertyNames(row)?.map((head) => {
                    return (
                      <div key={head} className="row my-2">
                        <div className="col-5">{createHeads(head)}</div>
                        <div className="col-7">{createInputs(head)}</div>
                        <div className="col-12">
                          <small className="text-danger">{errors.head?.message}</small>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
```

So `head` is a variable that contains the name of the input field. but it's not using that variable . is there a way around it?

--Edit

```
function createInput(head){
  return <input type="text" name="head" {...register(head)} />
}
```

Comment: Can you share some more relevant code? `createInputs` What's the structure of `row`? etc..

Comment: `errors[head.name].message?`

Comment: @SanishJoseph I updated it . the problem is that  ```errors.head.```  is it will be finds head  in errors object. where it should be the name of the input. ```errors.head``` not ```errors.Name```

Comment: @jaysurya its not working

Comment: I assumed head would have a key called `name`, what is the structure of `row` and `head` look like? also does the form have nested field names?

Comment: row is a object and head is its property and im looping through all properites and getting their values and assign them to input fields

Comment: ```Object.getOwnPropertyNames(errors).filter((item) => item == head))``` this seems to get head name . but still cant access message . only the correct head name

Comment: What about `errors[head].message`? Assuming `head` is the name of the field.

Comment: I dont know how did I miss that  :pain . it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
{Object?.getOwnPropertyNames(row)?.map((head) => {
                    const error = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(errors).filter((error) => error == head);

                    return (
                      <div key={head} className="row my-2">
                        <div className="col-5">{createHeads(head)}</div>
                        <div className="col-7">{createInputs(head)}</div>
                        <div className="col-12">
                          <small className="text-danger">{errors[error]?.message}</small>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
```

**Update**
*im just dumb*
edit :

```
{Object?.getOwnPropertyNames(row)?.map((head) => {
                    return (
                      <div key={head} className="row my-2">
                        <div className="col-5">{createHeads(head)}</div>
                        <div className="col-7">{createInputs(head)}</div>
                        <div className="col-12">
                          <small className="text-danger">{errors[head]?.message}</small>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 